# Is "tamal" or "tamale" correct when referring to this food in the singular?

Tags: comida, plurales

Which is the correct spelling when referring to this food in the singular?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En español se usa `tamal`. En el diccionario de la Real Academia Española encontramos [*tamal*](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=tamal)

> 1. Especie de empanada de masa de harina de maíz [...]
> 2. Lío, embrollo, pastel, intriga.

["Tamale"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamale) es simplemente la voz inglesa para ["tamal"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamal). El plural de `tamal` es `tamales`, por lo que en plural coinciden ambas palabras en español e inglés.